# It should be just as easy to unsubscribe as it is to subscribe to a forum here

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, unsubscribe

This question was part of the old website and I am now re-entering so it can be addressed in time. (Not that I want to unsubscribe at this stage - I think it is only good courtesy from the site owners to allow subscribers to unsubscribe)

EDIT: Just to clarify - Content can stay, but user must go if he wants to.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/possibility-to-delete-our-account

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate.

Comment: Similar though.

Comment: Ok - similar. :)

Comment: I don't really see what benefit being able to unsubscribe would bring, can someone point this out?

Comment: Benefit to SO: They know what their active / associated user count is, Benefit to user: They know they have been disassociated (completely anonymized) when they choose to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I don't even know what the process is to close your account here.  A little quick poking around on the user page didn't reveal anything, which is odd.  You ought to be able to close your account on any member of the SO family, or across all of them, fairly easily.

What you *shouldn't* be able to do is to close your account and expect all your content to go with it.  That stuff is all under the CC-Wiki license.  Of course, there's nothing stopping you from deleting as much of your stuff as the system will allow before you go...

Comment: I do not mind the content staying - it can be linked to a "anoymous" user or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I take it you are talking about deleting your account.

Send an email to team@stackoverflow.com and they will be able to help out whenever you need it (and they are typically very responsive).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could always just stop coming?

If you really want, it is easy for us to delete your account to prevent you returning; however, we would prefer not to delete your content (unless there is a strong whiff of "troll"/"spam" about you). In particular, that content is *already* covered by cc-wiki, and is probably available both in google search results and in the public db dump.

We'd also prefer not to remove (for example) accepted answers; if the answer is good, it should stay!

Here's an option if you want:

- edit your profile and change your display name to be "somebody" or something
- then flag a moderator (or e-mail the team) and ask your account to be *deleted but keeping the content*; easily done, but we'll probably ask you to verify your account, for example by adding "yes Marc, it is me" to your profile (or similar) or by e-mail, or both (and yes, we can see old e-mail addresses too; so hijacking an account can't destroy all trace of an original e-mail address)

we can then (**in theory**) drop your account. But we'll be sorry to see you leave, and I really don't want to do this (I haven't deleted a "bona fide" user to date...). Please stay ;-p I'd also probably double-check with Jeff before I start doing this!

One caveat: all negatively voted posts are automatically deleted when dropping a user account, even if we choose to keep the "good" content.

Comment: Hey - we are programmers that automate things very securely - why the manual labour? :)

Comment: Because it is hardly ever needed (so not worth the investment), and when it is, it needs thought and care.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason there is no ability to unsubscribe is because there is no ability to subscribe in the first place.

You go to SO or SF and you log in.  Then you log out.  If you want to put in details about yourself in your profile you can, but you don't have to.  I think that's the whole point of OpenID, so that you can avoid the subscription model altogether.

If someone wants to "unsubscribe" it would be a simple matter of removing all their profile content, and logging out.

Comment: Your openid is still linked to your profile though..

Comment: @mm2010 but why does it matter that your openid is pointing to a completely blank profile?  Which, by the way, is essentially the same behavior for someone who is new anyway, except you get to hold onto your rep, which is better than having to start over.

Comment: It means you are subscribed, even if it is via an openid. The whole point of this suggestion is to undo that link.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible; you can self-delete accounts provided they are relatively new, and have no content attached.