# Provide a UI for getting rid of accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possibility to delete our account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/possibility-to-delete-our-account)

I think that a lot of OpenID issues could be made 10% less agonizing if users had an easy way of deleting their own accounts, and merging them with other accounts.  Please provide this functionality.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/possibility-to-delete-our-account

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot less agonizing (and probably with fewer negative repercussions) if people just emailed team@stackoverflow.com when they needed this done.

Comment: I was just downvoted in a separate thread (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3952#3952), presumably by this user, for saying this exact thing.

Comment: Kyle: Looks like I just got DV'ed for it as well.

Comment: Yes, emailing them is great.  We should just email them all of our questions and have them post them instead of using a form too. :)

Honestly, emailing them is confusing too.  What information should I include?  How long is the response time?  Do I even understand enough about the intersection of how SO works/how OpenID works/how my provider works to give them a good explanation of the problem?  The current UI is terrible.  If I add a new provider to and to an existing account, the user fdbk is completely counterintuitive.  I know the team is bent on not fixing this, but they should fix it.

Comment: @jsight: Never had a problem. Try myopenid.com.

Comment: The turnaround time for getting problems like this taken care of is pretty minimal. And it takes a lot less effort than going on MetaSO tantrums.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the rare occurrences of this, emailing team@stackoverflow.com is just fine. Anything more complex is only likely to end in more support requests and problems.

Answer (score 0):

Accounts get deleted automagically after a period of inactivity and < 100 rep, but I like the idea of being able to manually disassociate your OpenID would be a good feature to have, especially if your OpenID were to get compromised in any way, shape or form.