# Will you please loosen the delete account restrictions?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-accounts

Currently you can only delete your account if you [have no posts and no votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/possibility-to-delete-our-account/101944#101944).  I'd prefer to not have a bunch of accounts listed on my user page that I don't and haven't used.  It would be great if you allowed people to delete their accounts if they don't have any posts (questions/answers), ignoring the no-vote requirement (or allowing you to delete if less than say 10 or 20 votes).

Comment: I didn't even know it was possible to self-delete accounts at all. Interesting. Looks like I have an account that at face value fits the requirements, but there's no "delete" option.

Comment: @AnnaLear I found one of mine and it _did_ have the delete option (although 1 vote had been cast)

Comment: @BartKiers I know where it's supposed to be (and I found it on other accounts of mine), but just not on this specific one. I'm probably gonna have to make meta post about it to see what's what.

Comment: @AnnaLear. ah, I see.

Comment: I understand why it would be messy to delete an account that has had activity, but it would certainly be nice if it were possible to delete an account regardless of activity. After all, while it may require a bunch of clean up, it’s not exactly a frequent activity—it’s kind of a one-time event. (I suppose however that it could open up the possibility of various exploits/abuses/attacks/etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You [can delete an account with activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979) by editing your profile and emailing a request (along with your user ID) to the staff.

Comment: Yeah, mods can both "delete" and "destroy" accounts. "destroy" is only for (IIRC) <500 rep accounts, and completely wipes it out (_all_ posts, and possibly votes). "delete" only removes certain posts (IIRC negative score). Not sure about votes.

Comment: Association bonus for having 200+ rep on another site?

Comment: You can get reputation for having suggested edits accepted. No need for posting.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about those (but can’t help but wonder if they factor into the restrictions and were simply omitted from the list).